# How to fix 'can't assign to operator' error with custom module

Tags: python

I am trying to create a caesar cipher, I created my own dictionary module and called in a for loop. The code is supposed to take an the i index of the input message and convert it to a number (via the dictionary module) add a cipher number input, convert it back to a new encrypted letter, and print it. The problem is that when I run it, I get an error message saying can't assign to operator. How can I fix this?

I have tried changing the i range, however I am afraid that it may be something with the module I made. I don't really understand the error message, so can you help me figure out the coding error?

This is my module code:

```py
>>> import pprint, shelve, os, sys, shutil
>>> alphanum = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6,'g':7,'h':8,'i':9,'j':10,'k':11,'l':12,'m':13,'n':14,'o':15,'p':16,'q':17,'r':18,'s':19,'t':20,'u':21,'v':22,'w':23,'x':24,'y':25,'z':26}
>>> pprint.pformat(alphanum)
"{'a': 1,\n 'b': 2,\n 'c': 3,\n 'd': 4,\n 'e': 5,\n 'f': 6,\n 'g': 7,\n 'h': 8,\n 'i': 9,\n 'j': 10,\n 'k': 11,\n 'l': 12,\n 'm': 13,\n 'n': 14,\n 'o': 15,\n 'p': 16,\n 'q': 17,\n 'r': 18,\n 's': 19,\n 't': 20,\n 'u': 21,\n 'v': 22,\n 'w': 23,\n 'x': 24,\n 'y': 25,\n 'z': 26}"
>>> AlphaCaesar = open('Caesar.py','w')
>>> AlphaCaesar.write('alphanum = {} \n'.format(pprint.pformat(alphanum)))
263
>>> AlphaCaesar.close()
>>> import Caesar
>>> Caesar.alphanum
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10, 'k': 11, 'l': 12, 'm': 13, 'n': 14, 'o': 15, 'p': 16, 'q': 17, 'r': 18, 's': 19, 't': 20, 'u': 21, 'v': 22, 'w': 23, 'x': 24, 'y': 25, 'z': 26}
```

and this is my caesar cipher program code:

```py
import Caesar
alphavalues = Caesar.alphanum
print('enter your message to encrypt')
message = input()
print('enter the cipher number')
ciphernum = input()
for i in range(0,len[encryption]):
    alphavalues[message[i]] + int(ciphernum) = newcaesaralpha
    print(alphavalues[newcaesaralpha])
```

Comment: What do you want the line `alphavalues[message[i]] + int(ciphernum) = newcaesaralpha` to do? This line is the problem -- it is not syntactically correct. I think you might have misplaced brackets.

Comment: can you show code of error?

Answer (score 1):

You have the assignment backwards. `newcaesaralpha` is the target, and must appear on the left. In addition, you need to use `%` to ensure the sum is between 1 and 26.

```
newcaesaralpha = (alphavalues[message[i]] - 1 + int(ciphernum)) % 26 + 1
```

(The algorithm is simpler if you number the alphabet 0 to 25 instead of 1 to 26.)